# The sum of all primitive $n$-th roots of unity in the algebraic closure of $F(x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, function-fields

If $n$ is any natural number, then $\mu(n)$ is the sum of all primitive $n$-th roots of unity in $\mathbb{C}$ where $\mu$ is the Möbius function defined as $\mu(n)=0$ if $n$ is not square free and $\mu(n)=(-1)^k$ otherwise where $k$ is the number of primes dividing $n$. Is it true in function fields? Say $F$ is a finite field and $F(x)$ is the field of fractions of the polynomial ring $F[x]$. Is it true that if take the algebraic closure of $F(x)$ and any polynomial $f$, the sum of $|f|$-th roots of unity is $\mu(f)$? Or is there an easy way to compute the sum of all primitive $n$-th roots uf unity in the algebraic closure of $F(x)$?

Comment: What is an "$|f|$-th root of unity" when $f$ is a polynomial?

Comment: $|f|$ is defined as $|F[x]/(f)|$, the number of elements of the corresponding quotient ring.

Comment: If $S_d$ is the sum of all $d$th roots of unity (primitive or not) in a given field, then Möbius inversion implies that the sum of all primitive $n$th roots of unity is $\sum_{d\mid n} \mu(\frac nd) S_d$. (The complex case follows from the fact that $S_d=0$ unless $d=1$.) So it suffices to evaluate $S_d$ in your favorite field.

Comment: Well I wasn't 100% sure whether Möbius inversion still holds in this case. Moreover, is it easy to compute $S_d$? Intuitively, it should be still $0$.

Comment: Möbius inversion is a property of the structure of divisors of integers $n$, so that's independent of what's being summed. I agree that intuitively $S_d$ should equal $0$ for $d\ge2$, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Well but we don't deal with divisors of integers? Instead, we take an Euclidean Domain and define $\mu$ similarly. I mean if $\mu(f)=0$ if $f$ is divisible by the square of a prime element in $F[x]$, and otherwise $\mu(n)=(-1)^t$ where $t$ is the number of distinct primes that divides $f$. Do you think it still works?

Comment: In $\mathbb{C}$ the $n$-th roots of unity form a cyclic group. It would be great if for any $n$, the $n$-th roots of unity would form a cyclic group in the algebraic closure of $F(x)$. Do you think it is true?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34725/discussion-between-greg-martin-and-m-levent-dogan).